# Having problems with creating a merge sort algorithm (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm having issues with the final implementation of merge sort. Below is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void decomposeArray(int* array, int length) {
    int arrayOfArrays[length];
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       cout << "Array: " << array[i] << endl;
    }

    if (length > 1) {
        int midpoint = length/2;
        int elemInFirst = midpoint;
        int elemInSecond = elemInFirst;

        if ((length % 2) == 1) {
            elemInSecond += 1;
        }

        int firstArray[elemInFirst];
        int secondArray[elemInSecond];

        for(int i = 0; i < elemInFirst; i ++) {
            firstArray[i] = array[i];

        }

        for(int j = elemInFirst; j < length; j++) {
            secondArray[j-elemInFirst] = array[j];
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < elemInFirst; i++) {
           cout << "First half: " << firstArray[i] << endl;
        }

        for(int i = elemInFirst; i < length; i++) {
           cout << "Second half: " << secondArray[i-elemInFirst] << endl;
        }

        decomposeArray(firstArray, elemInFirst);
        decomposeArray(secondArray, elemInSecond);


        int* superiorArray;
        int* inferiorArray;
        int dominantIndex;
        int inferiorIndex;

        if (elemInFirst > elemInSecond) {
            dominantIndex = elemInFirst;
            superiorArray = firstArray;

            inferiorIndex = elemInSecond;
            inferiorArray = secondArray;

        }
        else {
            dominantIndex = elemInSecond;
            superiorArray = secondArray;

            inferiorIndex = elemInFirst;
            inferiorArray = firstArray;
        }



        for(int i = 0; i < dominantIndex; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inferiorIndex; j++) {
                if (superiorArray[i] > inferiorArray[j]) {
                    int tempVal = array[i];
                    array[i] = inferiorArray[j];
                    array[(dominantIndex+j)] = tempVal;
                }
                else if (j == (inferiorIndex-1)){
                    int tempVal = array[i];
                    cout << "Array at i is " << array[i] << endl;
                    cout << "i is " << i << endl;
                    cout << "This temp value is " << array[i] << endl;
                    array[i] = superiorArray[i];
                    cout << "superiorArray[i]: " << superiorArray[i] << endl;
                    array[((dominantIndex)+j)] = tempVal;
                }

                else {
                    continue;
                }

            }
            cout << "Current array " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                cout << array[i] << ",";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }



        /*while ((firstIterator != elemInFirst) && (secondIterator !=elemInSecond) && (origArrayIter != length)) {
            if (firstArray[firstIterator] > secondArray[secondIterator]) {
                array[origArrayIter] = secondArray[secondIterator];
                array[origArrayIter + 1] = firstArray[firstIterator];

                firstIterator++;
                secondIterator++;
                origArrayIter+= 2;
            }
            else {
                array[origArrayIter] = firstArray[firstIterator];
                array[origArrayIter+1] = secondArray[secondIterator];
                firstIterator++;
                secondIterator++;
                origArrayIter+= 2;
            }
        }*/
        cout << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            cout << "Array coming out: " << array[i] << endl;
        }

        /*int tempArray[length];
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            tempArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        return tempArray;*/
    }

}
```

Specifically, the snippet that I'm having trouble with is merging the arrays back together:

```cpp
    for(int i = 0; i < dominantIndex; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inferiorIndex; j++) {
                if (superiorArray[i] > inferiorArray[j]) {
                    int tempVal = array[i];
                    array[i] = inferiorArray[j];
                    array[(dominantIndex+j)] = tempVal;
                }
                else if (j == (inferiorIndex-1)){
                    int tempVal = array[i];
                    cout << "Array at i is " << array[i] << endl;
                    cout << "i is " << i << endl;
                    cout << "This temp value is " << array[i] << endl;
                    array[i] = superiorArray[i];
                    cout << "superiorArray[i]: " << superiorArray[i] << endl;
                    array[((dominantIndex)+j)] = tempVal;
                }

                else {
                    continue;
                }

            }
            cout << "Current array " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                cout << array[i] << ",";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
```

When I use an array of values {5,3,8,2}, I am returned an array {2,5,3,3}. The step before the final array produces an array {2,3,8,5}. For some reason, I just don't know why the 5 and 8 aren't swapping. Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You do realize you are expecting someone to come along and debug your code for you, yes? Instead ask more specific questions, for example: "Why does this line of code give X instead of Y?"  or maybe "Where can I go to learn to debug my programs?" I'd down-vote this but who knows? Someone may actually finding it interesting enough to put in the effort.

Comment: i agree with DAV. You should debug your code by yourself.

Comment: or migrating it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: merge-sort is a good fit for linked lists. this is not a linked list. try [pivot-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: Instead of ranting, @DAV, just vote to close the question because it is indeed off-topic (due to violation of rules).

Comment: @ Ulrich Eckhardt,  I don't think explaining why it's a bad question is ranting. YMMV. I notice you didn't down vote it either.